# Why does this code not mutate the original array? Express API

Tags: javascript, express

I have a super weird bug in an Express API I am writing.  I want to look up a list of posts in the db (mongo) then add a property to each post object to send back to the client.

I am not able to add the `newProperty` below. It simply returns the list of objects from the database in their original, unmutated form i.e. without the `newProperty` property.

Why can't I add the new property?

Code:

```
exports.fetchPosts = async (userID) => {
    // fetch posts of users friends and the user himself
    try {
        // get friends posts
        const friends = await User.findById(userID).select('friends');
        const allPosts = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < friends.friends.length; i++) { // for each friend
            // get each friends' posts
            const posts = await Post.find({ author: friends.friends[i] }).populate('author', 'username');
            posts.forEach(friendPost => {
                friendPost.newProperty = 'newProperty';
                allPosts.push(friendPost);
            });

        } catch(err){ console.log(err)}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add newProperty

You weren't returning the new post data you wanted??  Honestly, it is kind of difficult to understand what you're looking for. See if running this helps.  You also had your catch statement out of scope, so this fixes that too.

```js
const fetchPosts = async(userID) => {
  // fetch posts of users friends and the user himself
  try {
    // get friends posts
    const allPosts = [{
        userID: 1,
        author: 'jack',
        username: 'jackStack',
        friends: ['bob'],
        content: '',
      },
      {
        userID: 2,
        author: 'bob',
        username: 'bobby',
        friends: ['jack'],
        content: '',
      },
    ];

    // Comment out my line and uncomment yours when done testing
    const friends = {
      friends: ['jack']
    };
    //const friends = await User.findById(userID).select('friends');
    for (let i = 0; i < friends.friends.length; i++) {
      // for each friend
      // get each friends' posts
      // Comment out my line and uncomment yours when done testing
      const posts = [{
        author: 'jack',
        username: 'jackStack'
      }];
      //    const posts = await Post.find({ author: friends.friends[i] }).populate('author', 'username');
      posts.forEach((friendPost) => {
        friendPost.newProperty = 'newProperty';
        allPosts.push(friendPost);
      });
    }
    // You need to return an answer with async 
    return allPosts;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

/*
 * * Comment out if you are done testing results 
 */
(async() => {
  console.log(await fetchPosts(2));

  // [object Array] (3)
  //[// [object Object] 
  //{
  //  "userID": 1,
  //  "author": "jack",
  //  "username": "jackStack",
  //  "friends": [
  //    "bob"
  //  ],
  //  "content": ""
  //},// [object Object] 
  //{
  //  "userID": 2,
  //  "author": "bob",
  //  "username": "bobby",
  //  "friends": [
  //    "jack"
  //  ],
  //  "content": ""
  //},// [object Object] 
  //{
  //  "author": "jack",
  //  "username": "jackStack",
  //  "newProperty": "newProperty"
  //}]
})();

// Uncomment when not testing
//exports.fetchPosts;
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/devnetkc/pen/vYryyGW)